# how to get another duplicate form without any text in the boxes as of the present form by clicking "next" button, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

this is the form details which i want to show again in the page when i click add another module button

```
    <div>
    <form class="in-line" id="module_info"></form>
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div align="left"> 
            <label >Module No: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Module no">
        </div>
        <div align="right" style="margin-left: 20%;">
            <label >Module title: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Module title">
        </div>
    </div><br> <br>
    <div>
        <label for="forInput">Objective : </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Objective" rows="5" cols="90">
        </textarea>
        <br><br>
        <label >Challenge: </label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="challenge" rows="5" cols="90">
        </textarea><br><br>

        <label for="forInput">Show How  : </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Show how" rows="5" cols="89">
        </textarea>
        <br><br>
        <label >References : </label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="References" rows="5" cols="88">
        </textarea><br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="extra" align="right"> 
     <button type="button" onclick="myFunc(this.form)">Add another Module</button>
    </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

please help me adding java script to get the desired output

Comment: Your form element is being closed in the second line itself. You sure this is the right code?

Comment: Are you saying his code is poorly formed, @gurvinder372?

Comment: @WilliamSchroederMcKinley Yes, I see one form being closed in the second line and one in the last line, but only one starting tag for form.

Comment: I know @gurvinder372.  I agree.  I was just making a joke.

Comment: @gurvinder372 actually, please don't consider the second line </form>, by mistake i typed , actually i need the code to clone the form.

please provide me the  javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the divs and the form.  I'd simply use jQuery's 'clone()' function.  I'd also add a div for the module.  Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/0jk6za14/4/

Actually, your form id is a problem - it needs to be incremented.  You can't have 2 items with the same id on a page.  I'm out of time for this now.  Let me know if you want that info.

Anyway, here's the script:

```
$('button.addModule').click(function () {
  addModule(this.form);
})
var addModule = function () {
  $('.modules')
    .append(
      $('.module').first().clone()
    )
}
```

and here's your modified code:

```
<div class="modules">
  <div class="module">
    <form class="in-line" id="module_info">
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <div align="left">
          <label>Module No: </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Module no">
        </div>
        <div align="right" style="margin-left: 20%;">
          <label>Module title: </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Module title">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div>
        <label for="forInput">Objective : </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Objective" rows="5" cols="90">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Challenge: </label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="challenge" rows="5" cols="90">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="forInput">Show How : </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Show how" rows="5" cols="89">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>References : </label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="References" rows="5" cols="88">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="extra" align="right">
  <button type="button" class="addModule">Add another Module</button>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, yeah, you're right, @Petroff.  I was going to.  Decided to keep it simple.  Fixing....